# Read more midi data

Tags: c++, midi

to read data from a midi keyboard I use the following callback function but: how can multiple data be managed? For example, when multiple keys (chords) are pressed on the keyboard at the same time?

```
void CALLBACK midi_in_proc_(HMIDIIN hMidiIn, UINT wMsg, DWORD dwInstance, DWORD dwParam1, DWORD dwParam2)
{
    unsigned char ch_msg, data1, data2, data3;

    switch(wMsg) {
    case MIM_OPEN:
        _tprintf_s(_T("wMsg=MIM_OPEN\n"));
        break;
    case MIM_CLOSE:
        _tprintf_s(_T("wMsg=MIM_CLOSE\n"));
        break;
    case MIM_DATA:
        ch_msg = (unsigned char)(0xFF & dwParam1);
        data1 = (unsigned char)(0xFF & (dwParam1 >> 8));        
        data2 = (unsigned char)(0xFF & (dwParam1 >> 16));       
        data3 = (unsigned char)(0xFF & (dwParam1 >> 24));       
        on_short_message(ch_msg, data1, data2, data3);
        break;
    default:
        _tprintf_s(_T("wMsg = unknown\n"));
        break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens at exactly the same moment; playing a chord will send a sequence of note on events.

Answer (score 1):

The MIDI protocol doesn't use the concept of "chord". What you call a chord is just a series of MIDI notes having the same (exact or approximative) timing. For instance, a MIDI sequencer doesn't need any chord when it plays the notes or present them in a MIDI editor. But when it displays the notes in a score editor, it must decide how to regroup them logically within chords, and for that it uses timings, but also pitch range, sometimes MIDI channels, and so on. This is something specific to the score editor job, not something that was intended by the MIDI protocol.

Anyway, notes having a same timing are received sequentially exactly as others. So you have to analyse the received data to decide if they are member of a chord.

Comment: Yes it is. To detect chords you'll need something more sophisticated than simply regrouping notes having exact same timings. For instance you could 'quantize' (round) these timings on a grid in sixteenths. But to do that you'll first have to figure out what is the duration of a sixteenth from timings probably expressed in milliseconds (you'll need to choose a tempo to do the conversion) and where is the beginning of your grid.